# Using the result from one API as a parameter for another and inserting both results into a JSON array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, handlebars.js

So I have 2 APIs:

localhost:8080/projects (gives me the list of the projects I have)

localhost:8080/tasks/{projectid} (gives me the list of tasks related to the project ID I used as parameter)

I'm using nodejs to fetch the results of the first API, then insert them into a JSON array and at the same time get each id from that same request and use them in the second api to fetch the tasks, finally I'd fetch those tasks and insert them into the same JSON array as the projects.

But I've run into a problem, after completing the operation I'd try to show the JSON array just to find out that it only contains the project names (which are the results from the first API), without finding the info from the second one.

Here's the methods I used:

first I made 2 methods, one to get the projects, and one to get the tasks, I used callbacks in both methods:

```
const projects = (callback) =>{
const url='localhost:8080/projects'
request({url,json:true},(error,{body}) =>{
    if(error){
        callback('error')
    }else{
        callback(undefined,body)
    }
})
}
```

```
const tasks = (projectid,callback) =>{
    const url='localhost:8080/tasks/'+encodeURIComponent(projectid)
    request({url,json:true},(error,{body})=>{
        if(error){
            callback('unable to find data')
        }else{
            callback(undefined,body)
=        }
    })
}
```

then I used express to define routes for these 2 methods:

```
app.get('/projects',(req,res)=>{
    func.projects((error,body)=>{
    if(error){
        return res.send({
            error : error
        })
    }
  res.send(body)
    })
})


app.get('/tasks',(req,res)=>{
    func.tasks(req.query.code,(error,body)=>{
        if(error){
            return res.send({
                error : error
            })
        }
        res.send(body)
    })
})
```

Finally I tried to fetch the data from these 2 routes into a json array using Javascript and show them in a handlabars page:

```
fetch('/projects').then((response) => {
    response.json().then((res) => {
        if (res.error) {
            console.log(res.error)
        } else {

            data = { todo: [] }

            //insert each project into our json array
            res.forEach((project) => {
        
                data.todo.push({ id: project.id, text: project.id })
                
                //Now we'll get the tasks using the project id as argument
                fetch('/tasks?code='+encodeURIComponent(project.id)).then((response)=>{
                    response.json().then((res)=>{
                        if(res.error){
                            console.log(error)
                        } else {
                            //add each task to the same array
                            res.forEach((task) => {
                            data.todo.push({text: task.desc, parent: item.id})
                            })
                        }
                    })
                })
            })
            gantt.parse(data);
        }
    })
})
```

Sorry for the long post I just wanted to explain all the details. Thanks.

Edit: The goal of my program was to use the json file as an argument for a gantt chart which is why I called the function called gantt, when I pass the json object the function only show the projects but now the tasks.

Even though when I use the console.log function it show that my object does indee contain the tasks. I think the problem here is that the function executes both foreach at the same time which is why It doesn't return the tasks since it doesn't have the required argument yet

Comment: Can you post the final output you got for todos?

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to specify that I'll edit the post now

Comment: done I added an explanation

Comment: Try to use generators to call fetch api for 2nd time for every project id. that will definitely work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you understand that `fetch` is asynchronous and that's why you have a `then` block where code is executed after the asynchronous operation is done. I have taken your example and then added inline comments with numbers indicating the flow of execution.

```
// 1. Starts execution.
fetch('/projects').then((response) => {
    response.json().then((res) => {
        if (res.error) {
            console.log(res.error)
        } else {
            // 2. Res has the list of projects.
            data = { todo: [] }

            //insert each project into our json array
            res.forEach((project) => {
        
                data.todo.push({ id: project.id, text: project.id })
                // 3. Fetch is called for each project.
                //Now we'll get the tasks using the project id as argument
                fetch('/tasks?code='+encodeURIComponent(project.id)).then((response)=>{
                    response.json().then((res)=>{
                        if(res.error){
                            console.log(error)
                        } else {
                             // 5. Data is push is to the array.
                            //add each task to the same array
                            res.forEach((task) => {
                            data.todo.push({text: task.desc, parent: item.id})
                            })
                        }
                    })
                })
            })

            // 4. parse is called.
            gantt.parse(data);
        }
    })
})
```

As you can see, `gantt.parse(data)` is called before data arrives for the subsequent fetch requests. This means you have to wait for all requests to complete before calling `gantt.parse(data)`. You can use `Promise.all` for that.

You also mentioned that `console.log` shows the data. That is because `console.log` usually works by reference. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` and you'll see the missing data.

To round it off, I'll add an example using `Promise.all` using a public API.

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(todos => {
    // I'm just taking the first 5 todos.
    todos = todos.slice(0, 5);
    const data = {
        todos: []
    };
    const requests = [];
    todos.forEach(todo => {
        data.todos.push({
            id: todo.id,
            title: todo.title
        });
        requests.push(fetchComments(todo.id));
    });

    Promise.all(requests).then(responses => {
        console.log(data);
        // Here is where you will call gnatt.parse
    });


    function fetchComments(id) {
        return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}/comments`)
            .then(res => res.json()).then(comments => {
                comments.forEach(comment => {
                    data.todos.push({
                        id: comment.id,
                        parent: id
                    });
                });
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: ah I understand now, I knew something was wrong with it but I couldn't fix it because I was still new to promises and such, thanks a lot for clarifying .